# How to rotate mapping of 2D controller

Tags: c, pointers, matrix, arduino

I would like to rotate the coordinate system of an Arduino Joystick controller I purchased.
The plane covers an area of 1024x1024 units and I would like redefine dynamically the orientation of the device.

This is what I've done so far:

```
void loop() {

  int x = analogRead(X_pin);
  int y = analogRead(Y_pin);
  int center = 512;

  float *transformed;
  transformed = rotate(
    float(x), float(y), 
    float(center), float(center) 
    PI/2.0
  );

  int tx = int(*transformed);
  int ty = int(*(transformed+1));

  Serial.print(tx);
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(ty);
}

float *rotate(float x, float y, float cx, float cy, float angle) {
  float out[] = {
    cx + (x - cx) * cos(angle) - (y - cy) * sin(angle),
    cy + (x - cx) * sin(angle) + (y - cy) * cos(angle)
  };
  return out;
}
```

Unfortunately all I'm getting is `0,0`.
Is there something wrong with the way I'm using pointers ?

Comment: Yes, there is something wrong. `return out;` returns a pointer to the first element of array `out`, but `out` ceases to exist after the function returns, so the pointer becomes invalid.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, how do you get this running within any form of real-time on Arduino? It doesn't have a FPU and you force it to do double precision floating point (and store the result in single-precision anyway). And also did you consider the actual calling convention in the ABI for passing all those floats around... passing 4x32 bit is going to be a mess.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
void loop() {

  int x = analogRead(X_pin);
  int y = analogRead(Y_pin);
  int center = 512;

  float *transformed;
  transformed = rotate(
    float(x), float(y), 
    float(center), float(center) 
    PI/2.0
  );

  int tx = int(*transformed);
  int ty = int(*(transformed+1));

  Serial.print(tx);
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(ty);
}

float *rotate(float x, float y, float cx, float cy, float angle) {
  float out[] = {
    cx + (x - cx) * cos(angle) - (y - cy) * sin(angle),
    cy + (x - cx) * sin(angle) + (y - cy) * cos(angle)
  };
  return out;//you return a local pointer so make memory problem
}
```

### I suggest like below using global variable

```
float out[2];//this declare before loop() and setup()

void loop() {

  int x = analogRead(X_pin);
  int y = analogRead(Y_pin);
  int center = 512;

  rotate(
    float(x), float(y), 
    float(center), float(center) 
    PI/2.0
  );

  int tx = int(out[0]);
  int ty = int(out[1]);

  Serial.print(tx);
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(ty);
}

void rotate(float x, float y, float cx, float cy, float angle) {
  out[0]=cx + (x - cx) * cos(angle) - (y - cy) * sin(angle);
  out[1]=cy + (x - cx) * sin(angle) + (y - cy) * cos(angle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`return out` - in this line, you're returning a local array from `rotate`. It has [automatic storage duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration#Storage_duration) and ceases to exist after `rotate` returns, and so by attempting to access it in `loop` you invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior).

Instead, pass an array to be populated as an argument to `rotate`:

```
float transformed[2];
rotate(
  float(x), float(y), 
  float(center), float(center) 
  PI/2.0, transformed
);
...
void rotate(float x, float y, float cx, float cy, float angle, float* out) {
  out[0]=cx + (x - cx) * cos(angle) - (y - cy) * sin(angle);
  out[1]=cy + (x - cx) * sin(angle) + (y - cy) * cos(angle);
}
```

Because `transformed` is allocated inside `loop`, it's still available to you after the call to `rotate`.